# Grails GoogleAppEngine no metadata problem

Tags: google-app-engine, grails

I am trying to run grails on google app engine using JDO,
but I got this:

org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: javax.jdo.JDOFatalUserException: No meta data for Book.  Perhaps you need to run the enhancer on this class?
NestedThrowables:
org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: No meta data for Book.  Perhaps you need to run the enhancer on this class?

I am confused, because when I did "grails app-engine package" it looks like the DataNucleus enhancer was running.

How can I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trivial fix,
I just have to put the domain class into a package, i.e.
grails create-domain-class packageName.Book

Comment: I am getting same error...can you explain your answer?
what do you mean by putting domain class into a package...?